# Contactform in footer of page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, wagtail

I have a contactform in the footer of a website. So it is on every page. It works, with one problem: as soon as it is sent, it doesn't show anymore. More specific I guess when my request is no longer empty.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/tags/contact.html', takes_context=True)
def contact_form(context):
    request = context['request']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['naam']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['bericht']
            messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['myemailaddress'])

        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('invalid header found')
        return context

    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return {request: 'context.request', 'form': form}
```

Tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are returning the template tag's context without the `form` whenever someone submits a form.

See below:

- Do not return the context object until the end of the function, this will make things simpler to work through.
- Best to add keys to the context object, this saves you from having to re-add `request` because it is already there.
- Remove the else branch towards the end, you want to send a new (blank) form all the time, even after receiving a response (via POST).

  @register.inclusion_tag('home/tags/contact.html', takes_context=True)
  def contact_form(context):
      request = context['request']

  ```
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ContactForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          subject = form.cleaned_data['naam']
          from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
          message = form.cleaned_data['bericht']
          messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
      try:
          send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['myemailaddress'])

      except BadHeaderError:
          return HttpResponse('invalid header found')
      #return context # returning here sends back the context without 'form'

  # remove the else branch, you always want to return an empty form
  #else:
  form = ContactForm()

  # return {request: 'context.request', 'form': form}
  # return at a consistent place in a consistent way
  # add to context, rather then recreating it
  context['form'] = form
  return context
  ```

Another workaround would be just to do a redirect back to the URL that the contact page is on (however, you will loose your messages).

Comment: Works like a charm, without a page reload! A small improvement might be to empty the form fields after submit. Although from a user perspective I am not sure if it would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have updated the answer to show that a new form should always be returned.