# Django - adding contact form to footer

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a contact form that can be used on all pages of my app.

My function `contact_form(request)` in `context_processors.py` successfully shows the contact form in all templates that my base template extends to, but the problem is that I can't submit the information and run POST requests with it.

After extensive research, it seems like the only clean way to do this would be to have `context_processors.py` perform the GET request and have a custom template tag handle the POST request.

Taking this approach, I can't find a way to process this in the template tag.  I have tried several different ways and have gotten several different errors.  I have also looked at many of the posts out there to get to this point, including [Contactform in footer of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370597/contactform-in-footer-of-page), and there doesn't seem to be any answers that show how this is formatted in the template.

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                 ...
                'services.context_processors.contact_form',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**context_processors.py**

```
from .forms import ContactForm

def contact_form(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        contact_form = ContactForm()
        return {'contact_form': contact_form}
    return
```

**tags.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('services/headerfooter.html', takes_context=True)
def post_request(context):
    request = context['request']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            from_email = contact_form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['t19clar@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            context = {
                'contact_form': contact_form,
                'from_email': from_email,
                'message': message

            }
        return render(request, 'services/headerfooter.html', context)
```

**headerfooter.html**

```
{% load tags %}

<form method="post">
    <div class="messages"></div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ contact_form.as_p }}
            {% post_request %}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" value="Send message">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was.  Since I am using class-based views for most of my views,  I needed to add a separate `post()` method to handle the POST requests as shown below.  This isn't needed with function-based views.  After figuring this out, I ditched the template tag and added all of the logic to `context_processor.py`.

**views.py**

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'services/home.html'

    def post(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

**context_processors.py**

```
def contact_form(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        contact_form = ContactForm()
        context = {'contact_form': contact_form}
    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            from_email = contact_form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['t19clar@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            context = {
                'contact_form': contact_form,
                'from_email': from_email,
                'message': message

            }
    return context
```